# Enforcing Content Type regardless of upload method

Tags: 2013, content-type, file-upload

being new to SharePoint I am struggling with this one and can't seem to find the answer - if there is one - in an other forum questions. Documents can be uploaded to SharePoint 2013 many ways:-

- Within SharePoint - Create document
- Within SharePoint - drag and drop
- Within Windows Explorer - Save As Favorites/SharePoint sites
- Within Windows Explorer - Save as... *after Adding a Network Location*

We want to enforce the user to choose from a list of content types regardless of how the document is uploaded and preferably without having to utilise check in/out, which is just confusing our users.

Is this possible and, if so, any advice would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a universal way. From my experience there is no simple way to enfore this but you might be able to via workflows.

You can add required to the columns which will force the user to in certian upload scenarios, mainly when saving direct from the document to a location or when saving after opening from SharePoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try enforcing the column to require something.  I'm afraid workflows are a bit over my head at the moment!

Comment: Thats expected. I have only been working with SharePoint for a little while and have asked this question before myself!